# How do I filter tweets in Tweetdeck based on multiple keywords?

Tags: tweetdeck

I have tried using everything I could imagine, space, comma, column , nothing seems to work. Is it possible to filter a column based on multiple keywords (ex: include all the tweets that contain "Unix" and "Ubuntu") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"keyword" or "keyword" or "keyword" or "keyword". Keep going but I really do not know the limit have not found that yet.Must have " around words and the or in between.

Comment: to simple to figure it out! :-)) Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems the current version needs OR not or to work

Comment: None of the proposed solution seems to work, either uppercase or lowercase

Comment: Currently, the following seems to work: "term1" OR "term2" OR "term3". The OR must be upper-case, the quotes do not seem to be necessary though.

Comment: None of these work - I tried both uppercase and lowercase or, with and without quotes.

Comment: today, some more advanced logic with parentheses also works ✅  e.g. -  #hashtag AND ("tweetTextA" OR "tweetTextB")